# asset image is not updated, how to fix this problem

Tags: flutter, pubspec

**i try to insert image to pubspec file, but it is updated, it shows this message,
"The asset images does not exist.try to creating the file or fixing the path to the file.",
how to fix this,
i format computer and tr**y to fix this, but i was unable to fix this, please help me to sot this out

Comment: Avoid hot reload and try running the app again. Also, add some code of your pubspec file and a screenshot of the image asset folder.

Comment: i try that, but it will not work, I have these problem  both  vs code and android studio ,

Comment: can you add your `pubspec.yaml` code and a screenshot of the file asset you got?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put assets upfront so that it looks like this

```dart
assets:
    - assets/img.jpg
```